# New Jobs Bug: Search Radius drop-down disappears too soon

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Firefox 43.0 on Win7 Pro X64

[image]

At this point if you move the mouse down to change the search radius, the dropdown closes, preventing you from changing the value.

However, the keyboard arrow keys can be used without the dropdown disappearing.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

1. This seems to be dependent on the state of the text box above and/or whether or not a search has been done.  Starting from a fresh page load the above behavior does not occur. The bug manifests only if you have entered a location and done search.
2. I cannot reproduce the problem on Chrome at all
3. On IE 11 the selection list of the dropdown remains but the textbox and checkboxes disappear when the mouse enters the selection list: [image]